# Argument 1 passed to League\\Flysystem\\AwsS3v3\\AwsS3Adapter::__construct() must be an instance of Aws\\S3Client, instance of Aws\\S3\\S3Client given

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services

I'm trying to upload an image file to AWS_BUCKET.
Here is my controller function,

```
public function createImage(Request $request)
{
   $path = $request->file('image')->store('images', 's3');
}
```

when I'm trying to upload an image using postman below error appears

```
Argument 1 passed to League\\Flysystem\\AwsS3v3\\AwsS3Adapter::__construct() must be an instance of Aws\\S3Client, instance of Aws\\S3\\S3Client given, 
called in C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\project-api\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Filesystem\\FilesystemManager.php on line 229
```

I tried several solutions. Nothing worked. Does anyone know how to solve this.?  Is there an error with my code.?

Comment: what your version of `league/flysystem-aws-s3-v3` in `composer.json`?

Comment: Please try to use `"league/flysystem-aws-s3-v3": "~1.0"`
`$name = $request->image_path; 
$file_name = $makeUniqueName . '.' . $request->file($name)->getClientOriginalExtension();
                    //Store s3 bucket
                    $upload= Storage::disk('s3')->put('uploads_folder/folder_name', $request->file($name));`

Comment: what version of Laravel is this?

Comment: @Lee  league/flysystem-aws-s3-v3     version 1.0

Comment: @apokryfos  Laravel 8

Comment: @SaimunHossain  it did not work...   Is there any other way or source.?

Comment: @TharinduMarapana
try this time:
`use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;`
`$contentFile = null;
        $disk = Storage::disk('s3');
        if($request->hasFile('image_url')){
            $file_name = uniqid() .'.'. $request->file('image_url')->getClientOriginalExtension();
            $path = 'folderName/'. $file_name;
            $disk->putFileAs('folderName', $request->file('image_url'), $file_name,'public');
            $contentFile = $path;
        }`
_make sure all credentials and other stuff are okay_

Comment: @SaimunHossain thanks much for your effort. I found the issue. There was a version problem with my "league/flysystem-aws-s3-v3".  It should be updated to version "1.0.29" Then now it works fine.  Thanks again.